# I want to add a css class selector to an onclick function in a vimeo-video slider/carousel plugin that came with a Timber template I bought

Tags: javascript, templates, slider, vimeo-player, timber

**Want to achieve:** a thumbnail gallery of video selections to work like a playlist. Each thumbnail is a clickable link to load & play their respective video in the central screen above gallery. 
gallery with player/slider above
[image]

And here's a bit of JS from the plugin, that (I think) is the function for clicking Next: (Demo Link Below)

```js
                var z = a('<a href="#" />').attr("id", "tms-prev").addClass("tms-arrow-nav").appendTo(b),
                    C = a('<a href="#" />').attr("id", "tms-next").addClass("tms-arrow-nav").appendTo(b);
                z.each(function() {
                    a(this).on("click", function(a) {
                        a.preventDefault(), p.autoAdvance && b.data("loaded") && y.resetSlideshow(), y.prevSlide()
                    })
                }), C.each(function() {
                    a(this).on("click", function(a) {
                        a.preventDefault(), p.autoAdvance && b.data("loaded") && y.resetSlideshow(), y.nextSlide()
                    })
                }), p.lazyLoad && b.find(".tms-arrow-nav").css({
                    display: "block"
                })
            }
```

**What I've done:** Linked thumbnails to use - a href target="name" to target the iframe for the central player screen. Since the video player is actually a slider plugin, I've run into a slight conflict.

**The problem:** Once integrated(my addition), the video loads on the second (of 3) slides on pause. User wouldn't know it was there, but - when the slider is rotated by clicking the NEXT arrow btn, the video begins to play from the slider's plugin function. This would be fine if the slider rotated from the user initially clicking the Play thumbnail. In fact, a preferable effect.

**Solution I'm seeking:** to include the classname for the thumbnail links in the plugin's existing click function where the NEXT slide button triggers rotation - basically adding my classname to $(this) of its onclick function, so clicking on any thumbnail link in the gallery will not only load the video (as it does now) but also trigger the slide to rotate, provided that the slider plugin plays video when rotated (as it does now).

**Options:** If problematic, I can go with disabling slider rotation altogether... if that would remove conflict to begin video play.

**Codepen:** Doesn't seem to work 
SO, I hosted a **demo online:** [demo of slider](http://skybluepreviews.com/demoB/)

1) the video playing at header on open is not the slider, slider is below this and directly above the gallery and says Slider Caption over a mountain icon. 
2) Only the top left thumbnail (2 Narbonne) is linked. When clicked, the video will load on the 2nd slide buit it wont seem like anything happened. rotate with the Next arrow and you'll see it. Feel free to use the demo in any way necessary - its only for this purpose.